# How to get list of columns from dataframe which start with specific value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-re

I have df which have different columns and some of them contains list and I want to get all the columns which contains list so I can run function only on them.

df:

```
Name      Test_Column1        Test_Column2           Test_Column3
A         ['a', 'b']           Test                   ['b']
```

So ideally i would like to get list of columns ['Test_Column1','Test_Column3']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want test all columns for lists use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
cols = df.columns[df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).all()].tolist()
print (cols)
['Test_Column1','Test_Column3']
```

If want test only first row is possible simplify solution:

```
cols = df.columns[df.iloc[0].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list))].tolist()
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't clean but you could do something like:

```
pd.DataFrame({"listcol":[[1, 2], [2, 3]], "normalcol":[1, 2]})
for col in df:
    if all(df.loc[:,col].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list))):
        print("all values in", col, "are of type list!")
```

instead of printing you can then save them. This only works if all elements in the column are of type list. You could switch it out for `any()` or your own check. I'm sure theres a cleaner way of applying this across columns that doesn't require looping but it escapes me.